# Query manager for the iSeries with autocomplete support

Tags: sql, autocomplete, ibm-midrange

Is there a query manager tool like SQL Server Management Studio for the iSeries that supports autocomplete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend [DbVisualizer](https://www.dbvis.com/) with the [IBM Toolbox/JTOpen](https://developer.ibm.com/articles/i-javatoolbox/) database driver.  The SQL editor supports auto-completion and more.

[image: DbVisualizer Screenshot]

Comment: Is this the free or the full version?

Comment: It's enabled in the [full version](http://www.dbvis.com/products/dbvis/features/index.jsp?feature=1).  Here's the documentation for [auto completion](http://www.dbvis.com/products/dbvis/doc/main/doc/ug/sqlCommander/sqlCommander.html#mozTocId409774)

Answer (score 0):

I have used [Aqua Data Studio](http://www.aquafold.com/) successfully in the past for queering iSeries and it does support autocomplete.